# How do I display inline-blocks vertically on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

The following code will display 3 inline-block elements, collectively centered.  I want to display these elements on top of each other, individually centered.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>A box</legend>
        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>B box</legend>
        <input type="Submit" name="NoOptions" value="No Options">
    </fieldset>

    <span>(Footnote)</span>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset { display:inline-block; }
form { text-align:center; }
```

I'm pretty sure (not entirely) that inline-block is indeed what I want; I want the fieldsets to be as small as possible (like a block), but I want them to be text-aligned (which only applies to inline stuff).  Is there any good way to stack them?

NOTE: These fieldsets may contain block level elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to size to content, center horizontally and stack vertically with just CSS. I would just wrap a div around each of the elements;

```
<form>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>A box</legend>
            <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>B box</legend>
            <input type="Submit" name="NoOptions" value="No Options">
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span>(Footnote)</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset { display:inline-block; }
form > div { text-align:center; }
```

Comment: Woah, this actually works!  I see what's going on; the div still takes up full width allowing individual fieldsets to size within it.  I don't know if this is more "semantic" than a `<br>`, but it works!

Comment: It's more or less the same as using `<br>`, but I prefer this way since it's easier to control the styling of a `<div>`.

Comment: Good point.  If you're the sort of person who cares about these sorts of things, `<br>` is also illegal here as I understand the spec. [HTML 5 BR Element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-br-element)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, flowing horizontally (like text) is one of the distinguishing features of `inline-block`.  If you want your fieldsets to be winched to their content size, but stack vertically, perhaps a combination of clearing and floating will work?

```
fieldset {
    /* remove the display: inline-block; property */
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}
```

**Update**

Off the top of my head, I don't believe it's possible to size an element to its content, stack it vertically, **and** center it horizontally with pure CSS.  To do that, you'll have to fall back to inserting breaks between each fieldset:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>A box</legend>
        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>

    <br>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>B box</legend>
        <input type="Submit" name="NoOptions" value="No Options">
    </fieldset>

    <br>

    <span>(Footnote)</span>
</form>
```

This, in combination with the CSS you're already using, should produce the effect you're looking for.

Comment: This makes the fieldsets block-level elements, which breaks the text-align attribute.

Comment: @Josh `text-align` works on block level elements, unless you mean these elements won't be affected by `text-align` then.

Comment: @alex I was referring to the `text-align:center` in the form tag, yes.

Comment: @Josh — You could also, of course, align them to the right by changing both instances of `left` to `right`.  I don't believe you can both center and winch with pure CSS, however.  For that, I think you'd leave your CSS as it is and insert `<br>`s between each fieldset.

Comment: @Ben I already knew about the `<br>` option, but I was hoping for something else.  I'm trying to be proper, but I guess I could compromise if there really isn't any proper way to do this.

Comment: The limitations of CSS really put a damper on my motivation to use it properly though.

Comment: @Josh — It's an unfortunate fact that CSS simply isn't great at winching to block content.  Typically, in a situation like this, you'd make all your fieldsets the same `width` and not run in to this problem. :-/

Comment: @Ben Well, I'm a bit disappointed, but I guess I'll either go with a <br> or a fixed width.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap them in a `<ul>`

```
<ul>
<li>
<fieldset>
        <legend>A box</legend>
        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
</li>
<li>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>B box</legend>
        <input type="Submit" name="NoOptions" value="No Options">
    </fieldset>
</li>
</ul>
```

You would then need to format the UL:

```
ul {
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}

ul li {
   list-style:none;
   text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: This is actually an interesting one, but I get some convenient bullets next to my fieldsets.  Can those be removed?  Even if they could, it seems somewhat un-semantic.

Comment: oh sorry ul li {list-style:none;} I'll add it to the answer

Comment: Nice, this might work.  Try it out, though, and the elements are off-center (they are centered as if the bullets were still there).

Comment: Add text-align:center to the li style as I have above.

Comment: Oh actually I don't think you can center the legned with text-align, you'll have to use margin-left on it. A lot of extra markup I know, but it's a way to do it.

Comment: Hmm it seems to be centering fine with what I am doing. Can you pastebin me your entire code?

Comment: @Chris I think I misread when I said that.  I think I'll pass on that solution, as it's pushing things a little too much for my liking.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need inline-blocks, that would put them side by side, you said you wanted them to display on top of each other.. that means you want them to be a block element in their own right, which they already are

remove this:

```
fieldset { display:inline-block; }
```

does that help?

you don't need lists.. not everything needs lists ;)

> but I want them to be text-aligned

with what? if you want the contents of a fieldset , i.e. the inputs to be vertically aligned  then they are already inline elements so should do what you want with the vertical-align property

Comment: If you try that, you'll see that the fieldsets automatically take up full width, which looks unappealing.  As far as I know, inlining an element is the main way to get it to close on itself.  Block elements typically take up full width.